# Add headers to request wrapped by ClientResource in Restlet

Tags: java, android, rest, restlet, clientresource

How do I add my own headers to a request wrapped by `ClientResource` in Restlet? For example, I've read that you can use the following when working directly with `Client`:

```
Form headers = (Form) request.getAttributes().get(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS);
if (headers == null) {
 headers = new Form();
 request.getAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", responseHeaders);
}
headers.add("X-Some-Header", "the value");
```

However, I am basically following the code provided in their tutorial and I do not know which member of `ClientResource` should be accessed to set headers:

```
ClientResource clientResource = new ClientResource("http://webserviceurl");

MyClassResource classResource = clientResource.wrap(classResource.class);

MyClass class;

try { class = resource.retrieve(); } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("fail."); }
```

What can I do to modify `retrieve()` to add some headers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ClientResource method has a getRequestAttributes method which is a shortcut for: `getRequest().getAttributes()`.

So you can use it in order to specify your custom headers for the request, as described below:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("...");
Series<Header> headers = cr.getRequestAttributes().get(
                                 "org.restlet.http.headers");
headers.set("<header-name>", "<header-value>");
```

Be aware that most of headers are managed by Restlet by default. To see which headers are supported, have a look at the HeaderUtils class: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/blob/master/modules/org.restlet/src/org/restlet/engine/header/HeaderUtils.java.

**Edited**

With latest versions of Restlet (2.3), a method `getHeaders` was added:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("...");
Series<Header> headers = cr.getHeaders();
headers.set("<header-name>", "<header-value>");
```

This corresponds to custom headers.

Hope it will help you.
Thierry

Comment: i'm get the follow error with this code:


Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Series<Header>

Comment: With version 2.1.2: 
        Series<Header> headers = (Series<Header>) res.getRequestAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
        if (headers == null) {
            headers = new Series<Header>(Header.class);
        }
        headers.add("user", "abcd1");
        headers.add("password", "welcome");

Comment: @thierry-templier sorry to inject into this conversation but can you help me out on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35383763/how-to-get-mediatype-from-request

Answer (score 3):

If you're using restlet 2.0.x (the latest stable version), you need to do this:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(yourUrl);
Form headers = (Form)resource.getRequestAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");
if (headers == null) {
    headers = new Form();
    resource.getRequestAttributes().put("org.restlet.http.headers", headers);
}
headers.add("yourHeaderName", yourHeaderValue);
resource.get();
Response response = resource.getResponse();
String text = response.getEntity().getText();
String status = response.getStatus().toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, so I'm sharing this.

```
        ClientResource client = new ClientResource(uri);

        Series<Header> headerValue = new Series<>(Header.class);
        Request request = client.getRequest();
        headerValue.add("header name", "header value");
        request.getAttributes().put(HeaderConstants.ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS, headerValue);
```