# How to get MediaType from Request

Tags: java, restlet

I'm building some kind of proxy server with Restlet, however I am having a problem that there's no automatic way to determine the `MediaType` based on the client request.

Here's my code:

```
Representation entity = null;
entity.setMediaType(processMediaType(path));
```

To process the media type:

```
private MediaType processMediaType(String path){
    MediaType type = MediaType.ALL;
    if(path.endsWith("html")){
        type = MediaType.TEXT_HTML;
    } else if (path.endsWith("css")) {
        type = MediaType.TEXT_CSS;
    } else if (path.endsWith("js")) {
        type = MediaType.TEXT_JAVASCRIPT;
    } else if (path.endsWith("txt")) {
        type = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN;
    } else if (path.endsWith("jpg")){
        type = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG;
    } else if (path.endsWith("png")){
        type = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG;
    }
    return type;
}
```

I was wondering if the MediaType can be constructed automatically by the framework (or by getting the MediaType from the request, which didn't worked for me) from the request such that I will not need to do these if-else statements which is very much limited in catching various media types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restlet get the media type of the request based on the `Content-Type` header. To the value, you can use this:

```
MediaType mediaType = getRequest().getEntity().getMediaType();
```

The media type hints of the ClientInfo corresponds to what is provided within the `Accept` header:

```
getRequest().getClientInfo().getAcceptedMediaTypes();
```

To get the mapping of headers in the Restlet API, you could have a look at this link:

- Mapping HTTP Headers - https://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/core/http-headers-mapping

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to determine media type ? Normally when you construct a rest api in java you create individual methods for each media type allowed i.e.,

```
@Path("<your_path>")
@Consumes (MediaType.XML)
@Produces (MediaType.XML)
public Response processXMLRequest (...){
    //a more general method to process all request
    return processRequest (request, MediaType.XML);
}


@Path("<your_path>")
@Consumes (MediaType.JSON)
@Produces (MediaType.JSON)
public Response processXMLRequest (...){
    //a more general method to process all request
    return processRequest (request, MediaType.JSON);
}
```

etc ...

Answer (score 1):

If you need it this information is available in in the `ClientInfo` object
 within the request.  Using the same mechanisms that Restlet uses to do content negotiation, which Em Ae's answer also automatically.

For example, within a `ServerResource` class function:

```
    List<MediaType> supported = null;
    MediaType type = getRequest().getClientInfo().getPreferredMediaType(supported);
```

Where you supply the list of supported `MediaTypes` in the most applicable way.

Comment: This is like `getPreferredMediaType(null);` ?

Comment: @xybrek at the moment yes it is I leave supplying the List of `MediaType`s that you support to you as you may wish to hard code it, obtain it from a static constant or some other means the simplest solution would be `Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.TEXT_CSS, ..., etc);` but I do not have enough context in your question to suggest this as being correct.  basically replace the `null` above with your list of types you support.